# How do I style a div to make it run with the text?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a small text-height div run with the text. My code looks like this:

```
blah blah blah <div style="display:block; float: left; width: 100px">[IN A DIV]</div> blah
```

it should come out to look like:

```
blah blah blah [IN A DIV] blah blah
```

but it always comes out as:

```
blah blah blah 
[IN A DIV]
blah blah
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you want a `<div>`? `<div>` is a block-level element and not meant for what you want.

Try a `<span>`, as that is what should be used for inline stuff and would be more semantically accurate.

Required reading: [Block and Inline elements](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline.php).

Comment: @laxj11: If this solved your problem, you should except an answer

Comment: hehe. couldn't do that when I originally asked this question

Answer (score 2):

Change `display:block` to `display:inline`

Answer (score 2):

That's because a `<div>` is a block-level element. A block will always break up the flow of the objects around it.  You either want to set your `<div>` to `display: inline;` or use a `<span>` instead.  Spans are inline by default.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:inline` instead of `display:block` or better yet use a **SPAN** instead of a **DIV**

Answer (score 1):

display: inline; and get rid of the float.

Answer (score 1):

use a <span>, which is the inline equivalent of a div.